# How to Schedule a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mysql

We had created a trigger for inserting a set of rows.
I want to schedule this trigger automatically and insert these data into another table. i.e, it has to execute automatically based on the period given.
Kindly suggest the possibilities steps for this.

Here i give you the clear explanation about the operation,
My project to transfer the data from MS SQL database table to MY SQL Database table. This event has to be scheduled. I have to select few fields from MS Sql table and that selected data to be transfer to My Sql table Automatically based on Scheduled.

Comment: you can't schedule a trigger!! It's only execute when insert,update or delete happen on the table where that trigger is associate !!  My be your question is wrong !!

Comment: cron job is what you looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use mysql event scheduler to configure and run your job.

Please have look into 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html

Comment: Here i give you the clear explanation about the operation, My project to transfer the data from MS SQL database table to MY SQL Database table. This event has to be scheduled. I have to select few fields from MS Sql table and that selected data to be transfer to My Sql table Automatically based on Scheduled

Comment: You gave an explanation, and the answer here is to use the MySQL event scheduler. If that can't work for you, please describe what the problem is with using it, including showing what you tried and any incorrect results. The link in the answer points to documentation of the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

First, Trigger is one database object and trigger created over the any physical table. this is depends on table action so at every action of table trigger will execute. 
we cant schedule trigger to execute on perticluar time. 
There is alternative solution is: Enable and Disable trigger using scedule SQL Job. 
Script is :

```
--To Enalble Trigger
ENABLE TRIGGER [Trigger_Name] ON [TableName]
GO

--To Disable Trigger
DISABLE TRIGGER [Trigger_Name] ON [TableName]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS SQL, then you can use SQL Server Agent to schedule a job/task to execute whatever you need done.

You can read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Your best bet maybe to create a stored procedure and then in the scheduled job, simply execute that stored procedure to run.

Alternatively, if you don't have SQL Server Agent (requires full version of MS SQL not SQL Server Express) then you could possibly look into using Windows Scheduled Task to schedule a batch file to run periodically, making a call to the sqlcmd utility  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which you should be able to setup to execute your stored procedure.

Hope this helps.